# Extending BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingnavigator

I want to extend the [BindingNavigator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator(v=vs.110).aspx) so I can add extra functionality to it. One of the things I want to do is add a [ToolStripSplitButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) that will autosize the cells in a DataGridView. I've been able to add the button, but when I drop the control on a form, my button is in the first position. I would like to add this button after the Delete button. How can I do this?

Here is what the control looks like when dropped onto a form at design time:
[image: nav]

Here is the code:

```
public class DataGridToolStrip : BindingNavigator
{

    private ToolStripSplitButton AutoSizeButton;
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuAllCells;
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuAllCellsExceptHeader;
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuColumnHeader;
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuDisplayedCells;
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuDisplayedCellsExceptHeader;

    public DataGridToolStrip() : base(false)
    {
        //this.Items.Clear();
        //this.AddStandardItems();

        this.mnuAllCells = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.mnuAllCellsExceptHeader = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.mnuColumnHeader = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.mnuDisplayedCells = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.mnuDisplayedCellsExceptHeader = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.AutoSizeButton = new ToolStripSplitButton();

        this.AutoSizeButton.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
        this.AutoSizeButton.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.mnuAllCells,
        this.mnuAllCellsExceptHeader,
        this.mnuColumnHeader,
        this.mnuDisplayedCells,
        this.mnuDisplayedCellsExceptHeader});

        this.AutoSizeButton.Name = "AutoSizeButton";
        this.AutoSizeButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 22);
        this.AutoSizeButton.Text = "Auto Size";



        this.Items.Add(AutoSizeButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add your AutoSizeButton as the last into the array of controls passed to DropDownItems.AddRange ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [`AddStandardItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.addstandarditems(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `BindingNavigator` and and add additional items after calling `base.AddStandardItems()`:

```
public class DataGridToolStrip : BindingNavigator
{
    public override void AddStandardItems()
    {
        base.AddStandardItems();
        // Add addtional items here
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! Never thought to look at overriding the method